# Mountain texture (rock) looks very unrealistic?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I made a mountain in blender I used a rock texture I found and when I first rendered it looked very realistic, I lost the file so I recreated it, but it now looks fake. [image]

The first original.[image]

The recreation of the first one

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to add some displacement in your material

Comment: The first has a lot more light and shadows

Comment: your images are very dark. Anyway I think you don't give enough details about the topology of your mesh and your nodes organization.

Comment: Same rock texture? If so the biggest difference is the scale of the texture.